# How to validate a certificate chain from a specific root CA in C#

Tags: c#, security, x509certificate, ca

I have a certificate chain that looks like this: `root CA -> intermediate CA -> client certificate`. How can I validate that a received certificate is explicitly created by "root CA"?

To validate the whole chain is not a problem. This can be done like this:

```
X509Certificate2 rootCert = new X509Certificate2(rootCertFile);
X509Certificate2 intermediateCert = new X509Certificate2(intermediateCertFile);
X509Certificate2 clientCert = new X509Certificate2(clientCertFile);

chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(rootCert);
chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(intermediateCert);

if(chain.Build(clientCert))
{
    // ... chain is valid
}
```

The issue here is that the certificate gets validated against the (Windows) certificate store but I just want to validate it against a specific root CA.

I also thought that it would be possible to check if the `chain.ChainElements` contains my expected root CA. But what if someone sends me a valid chain from a different root CA and just adds the my expected root CA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The certificate chain API checks that each element signed the preceding element, so there's no way that someone can just tack your root CA on the end (provided you're not using something like a 384-bit RSA key with MD5 signatures, in which case they can just forge your signature).

You can encode any extra checks that you like, such as that you know none of  your chains will exceed length 3 (though you could just have encoded that in your root CA's X509 Basic Constraints extension).

```
if (!chain.Build(cert))
{
    return false;
}

if (chain.ChainElements.Length > 3)
{
    return false;
}

X509Certificate2 chainRoot = chain.ChainElements[chain.ChainElements.Length - 1].Certificate;

return chainRoot.Equals(root);
```

If you prefer the last line could be `return root.RawData.SequenceEquals(chainRoot.RawData);` (ensure they have the same bytes).

Some things of note:

- When you call X509Chain.Build() every X509Certificate2 object it returns via an X509ChainElement is a new object. You may wish to Dispose any of the objects you aren't returning (which may be all of them).
- Even when chain.Build returns false it will populate the ChainElements array so you can inspect why.
- The X509Chain object itself is Disposable, you likely want to Dispose it (which you might already be doing outside of your snippet).
- Disposing the chain won't Dispose any of the created certificates, since you could have been holding an object reference already.

Comment: Thank you very much. The thing I was missing was that chain.ChainElements contains the chain that was actually checked.

Answer (score 0):

The `X509Chain` does not work reliably for scenarios where you do not have the root certificate in the trusted CA store on the machine.

Others will advocate using bouncy castle. I wanted to avoid bringing in another library just for this task, so I wrote my own.

As see in [RFC3280 Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.1) the certificate is a `ASN1` encoded structure, and at it's base level is comprised of only 3 elements.

1. The "TBS" (to be signed) certificate
2. The signature algorithm
3. and the signature value

```
Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
     tbsCertificate TBSCertificate,
     signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
     signatureValue BIT STRING
}
```

C# actually has a handy tool for parsing ASN1, the [System.Formats.Asn1.AsnDecoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formats.asn1.asndecoder?view=net-7.0).

Using this, we can extract these 3 elements from the certificate to verify the chain.

The first step was extracting the certificate signature, since the `X509Certificate2` class does not expose this information and it is necessary for the purpose of certificate validation.

**Example code to extract the signature value part:**

```cs
public static byte[] Signature(
    this X509Certificate2 certificate,
    AsnEncodingRules encodingRules = AsnEncodingRules.BER)
{
    var signedData = certificate.RawDataMemory;
    AsnDecoder.ReadSequence(
        signedData.Span,
        encodingRules,
        out var offset,
        out var length,
        out _
    );

    var certificateSpan = signedData.Span[offset..(offset + length)];
    AsnDecoder.ReadSequence(
        certificateSpan,
        encodingRules,
        out var tbsOffset,
        out var tbsLength,
        out _
    );

    var offsetSpan = certificateSpan[(tbsOffset + tbsLength)..];
    AsnDecoder.ReadSequence(
        offsetSpan,
        encodingRules,
        out var algOffset,
        out var algLength,
        out _
    );

    return AsnDecoder.ReadBitString(
        offsetSpan[(algOffset + algLength)..],
        encodingRules,
        out _,
        out _
    );
}
```

The next step is to extract the TBS certificate. This is the original data which was signed.

**example code to extract the TBS certificate data:**

```cs
public static ReadOnlySpan<byte> TbsCertificate(
    this X509Certificate2 certificate,
    AsnEncodingRules encodingRules = AsnEncodingRules.BER)
{
    var signedData = certificate.RawDataMemory;
    AsnDecoder.ReadSequence(
        signedData.Span,
        encodingRules,
        out var offset,
        out var length,
        out _
    );

    var certificateSpan = signedData.Span[offset..(offset + length)];
    AsnDecoder.ReadSequence(
        certificateSpan,
        encodingRules,
        out var tbsOffset,
        out var tbsLength,
        out _
    );

    // include ASN1 4 byte header to get WHOLE TBS Cert
    return certificateSpan.Slice(tbsOffset - 4, tbsLength + 4);
}
```

You may notice that when extracting the TBS certiifcate I needed to include the ASN1 header in the data, this is because the signature of the TBS Certificate INCLUDES this data (this annoyed me for a while).

For the first time in history, Microsoft does not impede us with their API design, and we are able to obtain the [Signature Algorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.signaturealgorithm?view=net-7.0) directly from the `X509Certificate2` object. Then we just need to decide to what extent we are going to implement different hash algorithms.

```cs
var signature = signed.Signature();
var tbs = signed.TbsCertificate();
var alg = signed.SignatureAlgorithm;

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpnap/a48b02b2-2a10-4eb0-bed4-1807a6d2f5ad
switch (alg)
{
    case { Value: var value } when value?.StartsWith("1.2.840.113549.1.1.") ?? false:
        return signedBy.GetRSAPublicKey()?.VerifyData(
            tbs,
            signature,
            value switch {
                "1.2.840.113549.1.1.11" => HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                "1.2.840.113549.1.1.12" => HashAlgorithmName.SHA384,
                "1.2.840.113549.1.1.13" => HashAlgorithmName.SHA512,
                _ => throw new UnsupportedSignatureAlgorithm(alg)
            },
            RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1
        ) ?? false;
    case { Value: var value } when value?.StartsWith("1.2.840.10045.4.3.") ?? false:
        return signedBy.GetECDsaPublicKey()?.VerifyData(
            tbs,
            signature,
            value switch
            {
                "1.2.840.10045.4.3.2" => HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                "1.2.840.10045.4.3.3" => HashAlgorithmName.SHA384,
                "1.2.840.10045.4.3.4" => HashAlgorithmName.SHA512,
                _ => throw new UnsupportedSignatureAlgorithm(alg)
            },
            DSASignatureFormat.Rfc3279DerSequence
        ) ?? false;
    default: throw new UnsupportedSignatureAlgorithm(alg);
}
```

As shown in the code above, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpnap/a48b02b2-2a10-4eb0-bed4-1807a6d2f5ad is a good resource to see the mapping of algorithms and OIDs.

Another thing you should be aware of is that there are some articles out there that claim that for elliptical curve algorithms, microsoft expects a `R,S` formatted key instead of a DER formatted key. I tried to convert the key to this format but it ultimately didn't work. What I discovered was that it was necessary to use the `DSASignatureFormat.Rfc3279DerSequence` parameter.

Additional certificate checks, like "not before" and "not after", or CRL and OCSP checks can be done in addition to the chain verification.